# Как правильно работать с LiveData на Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, livedata

Есть код на Java в котором осуществляется подписка на LiveData и там функция "onChanged" вызывается без проблем:
[image]

А вот код делающий тоже самое на Kotlin, но функция "onChanged" никак не хочет вызываться:
[image]

Подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка?

Проект на Java: [Ссылка1](https://yadi.sk/d/6afcxRpna-SGbA)
[Ссылка2](https://github.com/genbachae/projRoomJava)

Проект на Kotlin: [Ссылка1](https://yadi.sk/d/m0pTBO_pPA8_Ww)
[Ссылка2](https://github.com/genbachae/projRoomKotlin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что у интерфейса `Observer` только один метод `onChange`, поэтому `kotlin` преобразовал его в лямбда выражение и получается что вы внутри вызова метода `onChange` создали локальную фунуцию, но вам это не нужно.

```
RecsLiveData.observe(this, Observer<List<Rec>> { Recs ->
        val lvMain: ListView = findViewById(R.id.lvMain) as ListView // создаем адаптер
        recAdapter = RecAdapter(this@MainActivity, Recs)
        lvMain.setAdapter(recAdapter) // присваиваем адаптер списку
})
```